# Show that inf(E=1/p)=0

Tags: real-analysis

4. Let E be subset of Q (with the usual ordering) consisting of all fractions of the form 1/p, where p is a
   prime number. Show that inf(E) = 0.

Here is my attempt to prove this. Suppose there exists a minimum of E min(e). 0

Comment: ...and the attempt is...?

Comment: Here is my attempt to prove this. Suppose there exists a minimum of E min(e). 0<min(e)≤∀(E). This says that zero is a lower bound of E. I can't figure out how to force zero to be the greatest lower bound?

Comment: I had the idea to prove this statement by contradiction.

Comment: why would you assume the miminum exists in order to prove the infimum exists and (and to say what it is)?

Answer (score -1):

First, clearly $\;0\;$ is a lower bound of $\;E\;$ as for any prime $\;p\,,\;\;\frac1p>0\;$ .

Second, since for all $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ there exists *a prime* $\;p\;$ s.t. $\;p>n\;$ (why?), we then get that

$$\forall\;n\in\Bbb N\;\;\exists\;\text{a prime}\;\;p\;\;s.t. \;\;\frac1p<\frac1n$$

Now, for any $\;\epsilon >0\;$ choose $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t. $\;\frac1n<\epsilon\;$ (why such a natural exists?), and then choose a prime $\;p\;$ s.t.

$$\frac1p<\frac1n<\epsilon$$

and you've shown $\;0\;$ is the highest lower bound, so it is the infimum of $\;E\;$ . It's easy now to see it can't be *the minimum*

Comment: I'm trying to show that zero is the infimum.

Comment: @DylanLee Of course. That was a trivial typo.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly